# Accessing mp3 files stored inside ngCordova/ionic iOS app

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am currently in the process of building an iOS app with ngCordova and Ionic. Part of the specification includes being able to access/play mp3 files stored inside the applications 'www' folder.
After experimenting I have been able to play a music file from an external URL, however when trying to use a locally stored mp3 I am having problems.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="editor">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Editor</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>

      <ion-content ng-controller="MusicController">
        <button class="button" ng-click="play('www/elvis.mp3')">Play</button>
      </ion-content>

    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the Controller/App:

```
var editorApp = angular.module('editor', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

editorApp.controller("MusicController", function($scope, $cordovaMedia) {

  $scope.play = function(src) {

    var filePath = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + src;

    var iOSPlayOptions = {
      numberOfLoops: 2,
      playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false
    };

    var media = $cordovaMedia.newMedia(filePath);
    media.play(iOSPlayOptions);

  };

});
```

When I "cordova build ios" and run this on a phone in xCode I get the following error:

> 2015-04-23 11:59:43.619 IonicProject[1487:375698] Unknown resource
>   'file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FB22B00F-9020-46C9-BBA2-674009BD84F7/IonicProject.app/www/elvis.mp3'

Comment: dont add www. just add play('elvis.mp3')

Comment: tried that and still getting the same error: 2015-04-23 12:22:50.374 IonicProject[1516:381092] Unknown resource 'file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D72C701B-50ED-48C9-99CC-B3D21D35A2C7/IonicProject.app/elvis.mp3'

Comment: First of all, use the $location for find current location and on basis of current url, change in local audio src. But you can use the below code for play audio in iOS app. Also you can play/pause with audio tag no need to add multiple button for it.

Comment: having the same issue, any luck so far? works fine in android...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the direct audio tag for iOS app in ionic and no need to do these thing (these are required for Android app). Just write the following code:

**HTML Code**

```
<div ng-bind-html="audioCall()"></div>
```

**Controller Code**

```
$scope.audioCall = function () {
    if ($scope.audioUrl) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml("<audio controls> <source src='" + $scope.audioUrl + "' type='audio/mpeg'/></audio>");
    } else {
        return "";
    }
};
```

Comment: You can use this one for local and external urls of audio